# How to parse Text and extract integer

Tags: parsing, haskell

I have this `Data.Text`

```
"Check: Find max among: 70, 102, 271, 40"
```

How do I extract the numbers from this text and apply a function to them?

Comment: As a string or an `IO` monad?

Comment: its a Text which I get as a param in a http get request

Comment: So the function is a word? Is there a way to isolate `max`,... What are the specs?

Comment: So I am getting this request from a server "Check: Find max among: 70, 102, 271, 40" and I have to send them a response which would be the maximum of these numbers

Comment: But it is possible that one queries: "Check: Find min among: 1, 5, -7". You need to specify the format on what are the names of the supported functions and where are they located in the string?

Comment: For this case we can assume that it will always be "Check: Find max among: 70, 102, 121,133 "

Answer (score -2, accepted):

For a `String` you can use:

```
maximum . map (read) . filter (all isDigit) . map (filter ((/=) ',')) words
```

Or for a `Text`, use:

```
import Prelude as P
import Data.Text as T

fString :: Text -> Integer
fString = maximum . P.map (read) . P.filter (all isDigit) . P.map (P.filter ((/=) ',')) . P.map (T.unpack) . T.words
```

You can then for instance write a `main` function to read the value from `stdin`.

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    x <- getLine
    putStrLn $ show $ fString (pack x) --to demonstrate that it works with Data.Text
```

Comment: @dfeuer: if one can imagine people to know Data.Text without `unpack`. Looks to me that that's only valid in the pre-google era, but anyway...

Comment: Indeed, I did that too.

Comment: The real problem is that people using `Data.Text` typically want their code to be fast. Converting the text to a string to process it tends to defeat the purpose. There are parser libraries specifically for `Text`.

Comment: @dfeuer: but in contrast to your first comment, the OP didn't ask that, so since your that precise, you can't assume that :P

Answer (score 2):

For various esthetic reasons I like this approach:

```
import qualified Data.Text as T
import Data.Text.Read
import Data.Either
import Data.Char
import Data.Text.IO as T

readNums :: T.Text -> [Int]
readNums =
  map fst .                 -- 5. extract the parsed numbers
  snd .  partitionEithers . -- 4. collect only the valid numbers
  map decimal .             -- 3. parse each substring as an number
  filter (not . T.null) .   -- 2. filter out empty strings (not necessary)
  T.split (not . isDigit)   -- 1. split on non-digits
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use many of the Haskell parsing libraries to parse `Text` types but for such a simple example I'd just break it into words, filter for the digits and convert.  As dfeuer is pointing out, there is a big difference between Haskell's `String` type which the other answers use and the `Text` type which you perhaps mistakenly implied.  For the text type the operations look quite similar but you don't have the Prelude `read` operation:

```
import qualified Data.Text as T
import Data.Text (Text) 
import Data.Char (isDigit) 
import Data.Text.Read 

myRead :: Text -> [Int]
myRead = map num                 -- Convert the remaining elements into Ints
       . filter (not . T.null)   -- Drop all empty words
       . map (T.filter isDigit)  -- Drop all non-digits in each word (including signs!)
       . T.words                 -- Chop the string into words

num :: Text -> Int 
num = either (error . show) fst  -- Throw an exception if it wasn't a signed decimal
    . signed decimal             -- Read a signed decimal
```

Comment: You *almost* get an upvote here. Two problems remain: 1. There's no reason to use `signed` if you're filtering out the signs. 2. It seems much more Haskellian to replace `either (error . show) fst` with `fmap fst` and the final `map` with `mapM` or `traverse`.

Comment: And (3), it doesn't calculate the maximum which is after all the question of the OP.

Comment: @CommuSoft, good point. That just takes another function wrapped around to do `fmap maximum`.

Comment: But also, the whole thing where you filter out all non-digits and then proceed to act as though there might be non-digits seems a bit weird.

Comment: @CommuSoft That isn't in the question and the method is apparent either from basic knowledge or from your own answer.  @dfeuer Right, but it's an exemplification of the existance of `signed` - not filtering out signs is an easy exercise for the reader, but feel free to make edits.

Comment: The question is: "How do I extract the numbers from this text *and apply a function to them*?". Where do you see that's not necessary?

Answer (score 0):

This code example shows a simple way to do it:

```
import Data.List
import Control.Monad

getLine >>= \line -> putStrLn $ show $ maximum $ (map read . words $ filter (/=',') $ line :: [Int])
```

Comment: @vikingsteve: had the same issue. Very important of course... Especially if one provides a few numbers...

Comment: Ok, thanks. Would `Data.Text.unpack` be appropriate to use in order to work with String functions e.g. `words` ?

Comment: The most appropriate is probably to use functions from `Data.Text` and `Data.Text.Read` (or some fancier parsing library) and skip the strings.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one-line solution that works on `Text`. It pulls numbers out of the `Text` into a list with the
[`sepCap`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/replace-megaparsec/docs/Replace-Megaparsec.html#v:sepCap) combinator, and then you could apply the [`maximum`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:maximum) function.

And since this is a parser, you can extend it to something more complicated than this example, like actually parsing the query instructions out of the first part of the string.

```hs
import Replace.Megaparsec
import Text.Megaparsec
import Text.Megaparsec.Char.Lexer
import Data.Either
import Data.Maybe
import qualified Data.Text as T

maximum $ rights $ fromJust $ parseMaybe (sepCap (decimal :: Parsec Void T.Text Int)) 
    "Check: Find max among: 70, 102, 271, 40"
```

```hs
271
```